# Phonegap - from SQLITE to $scope

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

i'm developing my first app in phonegap and i need to put the SQLITE query results into my Angularjs $scope.

i manage to query the db and extract data but cannot put them inside the $scope

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
$scope.albums.push(results.rows.item(i));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you define `$scope.albums = [];` ? what is `results.rows.item()`?

Comment: results.rows.item(i) is object containing the rows returned by the query. Yes $scope.albums is defined.

Comment: if its an object/array, then you should access it like `items[i]`